# How to handle Many-To-Many Relation with existed data in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I had three table i.e,personalinfo,groups_designation,groups_desig_category

- personalinfo:pid(personal id)
- groups_designation:gid(group id)
- groups_desig_category:gid,pid

Actually I have data in both table's (personalinfo,groups_designation).So we have provide one screen.In that,The user selects the group and assign personal id and the data pulled  into groups_desig_category table.In this scenario,i mapped like

```
Personal.hbm.xml:-

<set name="empwthgrp" inverse="true" lazy="true"  table="groups_desig_category">
 <key>
    <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
  </key>

            <many-to-many entity-name="com.aims.beans.DesignationGroupBean">
                <column name="gid" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>

</set>
```

Personal.java:-

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int pid,deptno;
private String name,designation;
private Address address;
private Address permentaddress;
private Set famildtlslst;
private Set empwthgrp=new HashSet();
public Set getEmpwthgrp() {
    return empwthgrp;
}
public void setEmpwthgrp(Set empwthgrp) {
    this.empwthgrp = empwthgrp;
}
public Set getFamildtlslst() {
    return famildtlslst;
}
public void setFamildtlslst(Set famildtlslst) {
    this.famildtlslst = famildtlslst;
}
public Address getPermentaddress() {

    return permentaddress;
}
public void setPermentaddress(Address permentaddress) {

    this.permentaddress = permentaddress;
}
public Address getAddress() {

    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getDeptno() {
    return deptno;
}
public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
    this.deptno = deptno;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getPid() {
    return pid;
}
public void setPid(int pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}
public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}
public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}
```

GroupingDesig.hbm.xml:-

```
<class name="beans.DesignationGroupBean" table="groups_designation" proxy=beans.DesignationGroupBean">

<id name="gid" column="gid" type="java.lang.Integer">
 <generator class="sequence"><param name="sequence">gid_seq</param> </generator>
</id>
<property name="gname"  type="java.lang.String" column="gname" not-null="true" />
<property name="description"  type="java.lang.String" column="description" not-null="true" />
<set name="grpwthemp" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="groups_desig_category">
 <key>
    <column name="gid" not-null="true" />
  </key>
             <many-to-many entity-name="com.aims.beans.Personal">
                <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
</set>
</class>
```

DesignationGroupBean.java:-

```
private int gid;
private String gname,description;
private Set grpwthemp=new HashSet();
public Set getGrpwthemp() {
    return grpwthemp;
}
public void setGrpwthemp(Set grpwthemp) {
    this.grpwthemp = grpwthemp;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public int getGid() {
    return gid;
}
public void setGid(int gid) {
    this.gid = gid;
}
public String getGname() {
    return gname;
}
public void setGname(String gname) {
    this.gname = gname;
}
```

Actually I trying session.saveOrUpdate(pBean).But its not working.May be can change one-to many and many-to-one instead of many-to-many relation.I think it is not suitable in this scenario.So,How to handle in this scenario?.If you using reverse engineering then it created as one-to-many and many-to-one relation? why?.Please help me.

**Update:-**

I am implemented in one-to-many and many-to-one relation hibernate whereas in database its many-to-many relation.then Its working fine and below pasted the hibernate mapping files with one-to-many relation ship

GroupingDesig.hbm.xml:-

```
<set name="grpwthemp" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="groups_desig_category">
 <key>
    <column name="gid" not-null="true" />
  </key>
                <one-to-many class="com.aims.beans.GroupAssignment"/>


           <!--  <many-to-many entity-name="com.aims.beans.Personal">
                <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>-->

</set>
```

Personal.hbm.xml

```
<set name="empwthgrp" inverse="true" lazy="true"  table="groups_desig_category">
 <key>
    <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
  </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.aims.beans.GroupAssignment"/>

            <!--
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.aims.beans.DesignationGroupBean">
                <column name="gid" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>-->

</set>
```

AssigGroupingDesig.hbm.xml:-

```
<many-to-one name="personal" column="pid" class="com.aims.beans.Personal" not-null="true"></many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="desigdt" column="gid" class="com.aims.beans.DesignationGroupBean" not-null="true"></many-to-one>
```

When will be came picture the  relation ship?.I have search many-to-many relation example's in web i.e,.

[Mykong many-to-many](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/)

Please help me.**My Question is when will be came/used many-to-many relation ship in real time?.**

**Update 2:-**

Thanks.Removing the inverse tag its working fine.But i have doubt regarding generation of deleting the query.Please check the logs

```
 /* load com.beans.Personal */ select personal0_.pid as pid0_, personal0_.name as name5_0_, personal0_.DEPTNO as DEPTNO5_0_, personal0_.designation as designat4_5_0_, personal0_.pddress1 as pddress5_5_0_, personal0_.pddress2 as pddress6_5_0_, personal0_.pcity as pcity5_0_, personal0_.pstate as pstate5_0_, personal0_1_.HomeAddress1 as HomeAddr2_7_0_, personal0_1_.HomeAddress2 as HomeAddr3_7_0_, personal0_1_.homecity as homecity7_0_, personal0_1_.homestate as homestate7_0_ from personalinfo personal0_, address personal0_1_ where personal0_.pid=personal0_1_.pid and personal0_.pid=?



delete collection com.beans.Personal.empwthgrp */ delete from groups_desig_category where pid=?




insert collection row com.beans.Personal.empwthgrp */ insert into groups_desig_category (pid, gid) values (?, ?)
```

why generating the "delete from groups_desig_category where pid=?".Plz help me

Update 3:-

Yes.Iam loading the data using session.get.becuase i got exception regarding the some of mandatory fields.that is reason i loaded the data then update the records

```
          per=(Personal)session.get(Personal.class,new Integer(pBean.getPid()));
    per.setEmpwthgrp(pBean.getEmpwthgrp());
    session.saveOrUpdate(per);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your many-to-many mappings, you set **both** of them to **inverse**. You need to choose one entity that will **own** the relationship - for that one, in the mapping, you will remove the `inverse="true"` setting. That will be the entity that, when saved or updated, will persist the person to group relationship.

Since in your question you posted `saveOrUpdate(pBean)`, and I assume `pBean` is `Personal` entity, then you need to remove the `inverse="true"` setting in `Personal.hbm.xml`.

More info in the reference documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m

Comment: Thanks nicolae.Its working fine.I have doubt please check the udate 2 comment in th above regarding the generation "delete" query.Please help me

Comment: @user1357722 Does the delete happen when you are updating an existing Personal? If updating, please show the code block that is doing the update (this would show if you are, for example, obtaining a Personal throught load(), then altering the many-to-many collection which is a PersistentSet in this case OR using a Set that is not the one returned by Hibernate).

Comment: @user1357722 Since the problem with the delete, then insert is unrelated to this question, I would prefer if you would create another question. This way, anyone else that might bump into the same problem will find the solution easier. Create a new question, post the link to it here and I (and others) will try to answer.